# React to classes added via Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a menu on my website that is displayed and hidden when users click on a link.

Normally, I would use toggle for this. However, I have other menus on the page and so need to close them when this is displayed (I am also applying/removing animations classes). So I think the best way of doing this is by adding a class of `close` to the link and then reacting to that added class (as the other menus also have that `close` class).

However, Jquery doesn't seem to react to classes added via Jquery. I have searched around for this and found you can use [Live()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764908/jquery-click-function-on-a-class-added-via-addclass-does-not-respond) for this purpose. But, [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is now depreciated and you are supposed to use [On()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

The way to use On is as follows:

`$('.anchor').on('click', '.close', function()`

But it doesn't seem to work. I've also tried variations of this, but none of them seem to work.

How can I get Jquery to react to classes it has added.

**[JSFIDDLE Here](http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/6XVEA/)**

Comment: You should read this article to understand how event delegation works: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/. Also I don't see the from your question in the jsFiddle demo. I only see `$('.anchor.close').on('click',...);`.

Comment: Do you want to hide list on Menu click?

Comment: @AleksandrM I want to hide the list when you click on the Menu link. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @big_smile: Does my answer answers your question?

Comment: @AleksandrM, Yes it does so I have upvoted and accepted it (I only just saw the reply now, sorry for the delay!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind click events to document and remove class `.close` on `.anchor` click and vice versa.

```
$(document).on('click','.anchor', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('anchor');
  $(this).addClass('close');
  // ...
```

and

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function()    {
  $(this).removeClass('close');
  $(this).addClass('anchor');
  // ...
```

NOTE: it is better to wrap your HTML in some div and bind events to that div instead of binding it to the whole document.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mq5xX/

**Update**

Or even better change class on close link to `.anchor` and use this code.

```
$(document).on('click','.anchor', function() {
  $('.anchor').addClass('close');
  $('.anchor').removeClass('anchor');
  // ...
```

and

```
$(document).on('click','.close', function() {
  $('.close').addClass('anchor');
  $('.close').removeClass('close');
  // ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mq5xX/1/

Comment: The event don't need to be binded to document. The content is not loaded dynamically. The performance suffer for nothing.

Comment: @L105: OP wants thats same link would hide and show list. How would you do that without binding event to document or wrapping element?

Comment: OP is only HIDING the div not REMOVING it. It does not need to be binded to document. A simple $('.close').click(...) can do the job

Comment: @L105: Show working example w/o binding to wrapping element or remove downvote.

Comment: @L105: He is removing class from link that a bit different.

Comment: So bind it the the nav? Why document?

Comment: @L105: Have you read my answer? `NOTE: it is better to wrap your HTML in some div and bind events to that div instead of binding it to the whole document.`

Comment: You're right I made a mistake. I read OP text again and you're right, edit your post and I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your "close" link is not contained in an element with class "anchor". Therefore jQuery looks for it but doesn't find the element and cannot bind the click event to it.

If you use `$('.close').on('click', function () { ... });` it does work.

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6XVEA/1/)**

Comment: That works when you click on the close link, but it doesn't work when you click on the original Menu anchor (which also has a class of close). Thanks for your help!